# Getting an "Unexpected end of file" error

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm receiving an error saying line 44: syntax error: unexpected end of file

```
#!/bin/sh


touch $results.txt #creates txt file

now="$(date)" #records current date and time to be posted

echo "Name: Kevin Delrisco" > results.txt

echo "Date and time: $now" >> results.txt

echo -n "Enter a number between 1-50: " # asks user to enter a number

read n

while [[$n -le 1 || $n -ge 51 ]] do #while loop to check if number is over 50


        echo -n "Enter a number between 1-50: "

        read n; 
done

sum= 0

for (( i = 1; i<=$n; i++ )) do #for loop to add the sum

        sum=$(( $sum + $i ));
done

echo "Sum of numbers is $sum"
echo "Sum of numbers is $sum" >> results.txt
```

Comment: You may find [www.shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) (or the `shellcheck` package from the repo) to be helpful. Also note [DashAsBinSh](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
read n done
```

This reads two values from the input into `$n` and `$done`.

Insert `;` or a newline before `done` to make it close the while loop.

Comment: I did what you said i think? Now it gives me a "syntax error near unexpected token 'done' I edited the code to do what I changed

Comment: There are also missing `;` (or line breaks) before each `do`; missing space after `[[`; extraneous space after `sum=`; and the shebang is wrong - at least for the default Ubuntu where `/bin/sh` is the dash shell

Comment: Steeldriver ya fuckin solved it, thank you. I'm incredibly new to shell scripts (literally started this morning)